# How to get all the files and folder from the repository of pentaho bi server5?

Tags: repository, pentaho, saiku

I'm new to pentaho and exploring it. For my application I require the list of all the files stored in the repository of pentaho. I'm using saiku for analytics. Can anyone tell me how can I do that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your goal. Do you want to manually download all files from `home` folder on Pentaho BI Server 5?

Answer (score 1):

There is a REST API for most Pentaho BA Server capabilities, here is a link to the 5.2 documentation for the Repository-related REST API:

http://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.2/0R0/070/010/0A0/0Q0